# What is the difference in the use AES-128 and AES-256? How to change the StateMatrix or round operations?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, wolfram-mathematica

I did a simple realization of AES-128 which use only one round. I want to know how will change my StateMatrix or round operations if I will realize AES-256? I know that I have to use 256-bit key, but my message still have 128-bit lenght. I know that ShiftRow operations will change.

OK. For example, I have the following message which must be encrypted:

```
 message = "encryptionaes256";
 key = "keyskeyskeyskeys";
 px = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1;
```

Now I want to create my StateMatrix(I don't how to create AES-256 that's why my code will describe AES-128):

```
stateMatrix = Table[0, {4}, {4}];
partitionByBytes = Partition[ToDigits2Form[message], 8];
counter = 1;
For[j = 0, j < Length[partitionByBytes], ++j,
  If[Mod[j, 4] == 0 && j != 0,
   counter = counter + 1];
  stateMatrix[[Mod[j, 4] + 1, counter]] =  
   FromBitToGalua[partitionByBytes[[j + 1]]];
  ];
```

**ToDigits2Form**  transforms a message into a binary vector.
**FromBitToGalua** represents byte in GF(2^8).

The next step is creating key into matrix form:

```
keyMatrix = Table[0, {4}, {4}];
partitionByBytes = Partition[ToDigits2Form[key], 8];
counter = 1;
For[j = 0, j < Length[partitionByBytes], ++j,
  If[Mod[j, 4] == 0 && j != 0,
   counter = counter + 1];
  keyMatrix[[Mod[j, 4] + 1, counter]] =  
   FromBitToGalua[partitionByBytes[[j + 1]]];
  ];
```

But I have to use AES-256 my key must have 256-bit lenght. Does it mean that my matrix will have 8 rows and 4 columns? If it's true, how can I do my round operations? My StateMatrix which represent my message will be 4x4 and my KeyMatrix will be 8x4. How will it work?

Now I'm going to create the TransformationTable for SubBytes operation:

```
TransformationTable[Sbox_] := Block[{i, j, table, counter},
  table = Table[{0, 0}, {16}, {16}];
  counter = 1;
  For[i = 1, i <= 16, ++i,
   For[j = 1, j <= 16, ++j,
     table[[i, j]] = IntegerDigits[Sbox[[counter]], 16, 2];
     ++counter;
     ];
   ];
  Return[table];
  ]

table = TransformationTable[Sbox];
```

I don't put the SBox matrix. You can find it in the internet. It's looks like `Sbox = {99, 124, 119, 123, 242,.......}`

### Step 1. AddRoundKey

Now the first of round operations. It's AddRoundKey:

```
AddRoundKey[matrix1_, matrix2_] := Block[{i, j, result},
      result = Table[0, {4}, {4}];
      For[i = 1, i <= 4, ++i,
       For[j = 1, j <= 4, ++j,
         result[[i, j]] = 
          PolynomialMod[matrix1[[i, j]] + matrix2[[i, j]], {2}]
         ];
       ];
      Return[result];
      ]

stateMatrix = AddRoundKey[stateMatrix, keyMatrix];
```

Which size of result should I get? Maybe it's stupid question but I got stuck with it.

### Step 2. Replacement of elements of a matrix state by the rule sets the table

Now I want to transform elements of StateMatrix to hexadecimal system:

```
FromBitToGalua[byte_] := Block[{t1, t2, x},
  t2 = byte;
  t1 = Sum[x^(7 - i)*t2[[i + 1]], {i, 7}];
  Return[t1]
  ]
FromGaluaToBit[byte_] := Block[{t1, t2, t3, x},
  t1 = PadLeft[Reverse@CoefficientList[byte, x], 8];
  Return[t1]
  ]
From16ToGalua[byte_] := Block[{t1, t2},
  t1 = IntegerDigits[
    FromDigits[
     byte /. {a -> 10, b -> 11, c -> 12, d -> 13, e -> 14, f -> 15}, 
     16], 2, 8];
  t2 = FromBitToGalua[t1];
  Return[t2]
  ]
FromGaluaTo16[byte_] := Block[{t1, t2},
  t1 = FromGaluaToBit[byte];
  t2 = IntegerDigits[FromDigits[t1, 2], 16, 2];
  t2 /. {10 -> a, 11 -> b, 12 -> c, 13 -> d, 14 -> e, 15 -> f};
  Return[t2]
  ]
```

**SubBytes** operation:

```
SubBytes[matrix_, table_] := Block[{i, j, result, pos},
  result = Table[0, {4}, {4}];
  For[i = 1, i <= 4, ++i,
   For[j = 1, j <= 4, ++j,
     pos = matrix[[i, j]];
     result[[i, j]] = table[[pos[[1]] + 1, pos[[2]] + 1]];
     ];
   ];
  Return[result];
  ]
```

### Step 3. ShiftRows operation

```
ShiftRows[matrix_] := Block[{i, j, result, pos},
  result = Table[0, {4}, {4}];
  For[i = 0, i < 4, ++i,
   For[j = 0, j < 4, ++j,
     result[[i + 1, Mod[j - i, 4] + 1]] = matrix[[i + 1, j + 1]];
     ];
   ];
  Return[result];
  ]
```

And I have a question. Will I have the same shifting positions for AES-128 and AES-256? I use 32-bit block, 128-bit message and 256-bit key.

### Step 4. MixColumns

```
MixColumns[matrix_, tMatrix_] := Block[{c, i, j, result, col, el},
  result = Table[0, {4}, {4}];
  For[c = 1, c <= 4, ++c,
   col = matrix[[All, c]];
   For[i = 1, i <= 4, ++i,
    el = 0;
    For[j = 1, j <= 4, ++j,
     el += Multiply[tMatrix[[i, j]], col[[j]]];
     ];
    result[[i, c]] = PolynomialMod[el, {2}];
    ];
   ];
  Return[result];
  ]
```

Could you tell me what to change if I use AES-256? My message still have 128-bit and my block is 32-bit. How will change inverse operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES has a block size of 16-bytes for all key sizes.

he only difference in **using** a different key size is just to use a different key size, AES key sizes are 128, 192 and 256 bits.

The message size does not change based on the key size, it is determined by the message size, encryption mode and any padding.

Comment: Does it mean that all of my operations will work without modifications?

Comment: The number of rounds is increased for larger key sizes. 128-bit is 10, 192-bit is 12 and 256-bit is 15 rounds. See [Advanced Encryption Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). I assume this AES implementation is not for production, that would be a very bad idea.